# Monitor doesn't work as expected, if it is connected to a docking station instead of directly into my laptop

Tags: laptop, hdmi, external-display, docking-station

I have an older Dell monitor (Dell 2005FPW, to be exact), which still works fine, except for if it gets connected to a laptop *via a docking station*.

It can be any laptop and/or any docking station (powered or not) and/or any cable, the monitor displays the screen squished, with a black and thin pink/purple bar (image).

Is there a solution to this problem?

Close up of the Dell 2005FPW monitor, connected to my laptop via a docking station:
[image: Close up of the Dell 2005FPW monitor, connected to my laptop via a docking station.]

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? Does your docking station have any connection to a physical HDMI port on the machine, or does it solely rely on a USB-C port?

Comment: The monitor might get its EDID wrong via the dock. Idea if you're on Windows : Download the utility [Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU), connect the monitor directly and export its EDID, then connect it via the dock and import this EDID. I suggest to create a System Restore point before doing the above, to be able to undo any Windows-level changes.

Comment: @TomYan Windows 11, solely a Thunderbolt port.

Comment: @harrymc As far as I understand the "CRU", it changes can edit the resolutions of the screens. Thing is, as far as I can see, the monitor doesn't get a different resolution from my pc, it just ever so slightly squishes the screen and displays a black bar on the side, together with a thin purple line (see image).
Why would it even be different if it is connected in a different way?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate possibilities : Forcing the EDID would assure that the computer will see the monitor identically when docked or not. If it doesn't help, then the problem is on the monitor's side and I think it will take a specialist in electronics to find out why. There are no firmware updates available for this monitor (not sure they ever existed).

Comment: Most docking stations does not passthrough HDMI signal though. Probably over 90% of them present themselves as a DP sink to the machine and convert the DP stream to HDMI signal. (Probably because HDMI alt mode was introduced much later than DP alt mode, almost no vendor bothers to make use of it; while for TB, which relies on tunneling instead of alt modes AFAIK, HDMI tunneling has never been a thing, I think.)

Comment: @TomYan My docking station has two Display Ports, one HDMI port, and one Display Port capable USB-C/Thunderbolt port. Problem is, I only have an HDMI to HDMI cable, with an adapter for DVI-D, so I can't really use any of the others. How would I resolve my issue in a different manner?